# Asking a non sensical question in response to another questions, meant to stump the original asking person. What is the name of such a question?

Tags: phrases

Is there a name for a question such as the one on line 3 below?

1. Rocket Scientist: Hi, how can I help you?
2. Dummy: Hi, there's a clunking noise coming from the left front rocket booster of my spaceship.  Would you be able to please run some tests to determine the cause?
3. Rocket Scientist: What kind of tests would like me to run?

Obviously, "Rocket Scientist" is the expert here, and dummy isn't asking the right soft of question to begin with.   However, is there a legal or English term for the kind of question asked on line 3?

Regards,
CJ

Comment: Sounds like *playing dumb*.

Comment: Patronising/Patronizing

Comment: Also passive-aggressive.

Comment: Thanks everyone!